# elixir phoenix pubsub wildcard topic

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

when using phoenix pubs directly is there a way for subscribing to a topic with partial match, e.g. something like "user:*"?

just for illustration sake, the following code:

```
Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe("my_pubsub", "user:*")
```

should match **all** the following events:

```
Phoenix.PubSub.broadcast("my_pubsub", "user:123", "banana")
Phoenix.PubSub.broadcast("my_pubsub", "user:911", "apple")
Phoenix.PubSub.broadcast("my_pubsub", "user:", "orange")
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_pubsub/Phoenix.PubSub.html#subscribe/3) does not support wildcard topics. As noted in the [Phoenix Docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/channels.html#channel-routes), and by [this answer by Chris McCord](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_pubsub/issues/152), `channels` and `topics` can have wildcards in the strings, but subscriptions cannot.